# Update one table if value is equal in other table

Tags: php, mysql

I may have tried to reach too high this time, but I hope this can be done. I have a table called **liga** like this:

```
uid  |  name  |  games  |  points  |
___________________________________
1    | Daniel |    0    |    0     |
2    | Mikkel |    0    |    0     |
```

Where **uid** is short for **user id**.
Then I have a table called **kamp2** like this:

```
uid  |  k1    |  k1r    |  k2   |  k2r   |  week  |
__________________________________________________
1    |  1     |  2-1    |  X    |  2-2   |  14    |
2    |  2     |  1-1    |  1    |  2-1   |  14    |
```

These data is submitted by the user (attached to the **uid**).

Now, what I would like is a form, where I write the results of a soccermatch, something like:

```
<input type="text" name="k1">... and so on...
```

... and then I should write the correct results. So, to my actual question:

Let's say the first match (k1=the winner(1X2) and k1r=result) was 2-1, I would like the form to update the **liga**-table with something like:

```
If (k1 == 1 AND k1r == 2-1) UPDATE liga SET point = point + 5 WHERE uid = $uid;
else if 
(k1r == 2-1 AND k1 != 1) UPDATE liga SET point = point + 3 WHERE uid = $uid ;
else if 
(k1 == 1 AND k1r != 2-1) UPDATE liga SET point = point + 1 WHERE uid = $uid ;
```

But how is this possible? Should I SELECT the **kamp2** table first and then use it or maybe `JOIN` the two tables or how?
If this question is too "big" to answer, just let me know :) I don't want you to give me the exact code, just to guide me :)
Hope it's okay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the tables together and then do the update with `CASE` logic:

```
UPDATE liga l JOIN
       kamp2 k
       ON l.uid = k.uid
    SET point = (CASE WHEN k.k1 = '1' and k.k1r = '2-1' THEN point + 5
                      WHEN k.k1r = '2-1' AND k.k1 <> '1' THEN point + 3 
                      WHEN k.k1 = '1' AND k.k1r <> '2-1' THEN point + 1 
                      ELSE point
                 END)
    WHERE l.uid = $uid ;
```

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I come home :)

Comment: How do I make sure, that it chooses this week in the **kamp2** table? Next week the week-column will be 15 so I have to make sure, it uses that weeks row in the case?

Comment: @DanielJensen . . . If you have another question, then ask it as a new *question* not in a comment.

Comment: Got it! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can't update the same record with condition of that as well.

You need to use sub query to update that.

> UPDATE data_table t, (SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME, VALUE
>                           FROM data_table
>                          WHERE VALUE IS NOT NULL AND VALUE != '') t1    SET t.VALUE = t1.VALUE  WHERE t.ID = t1.ID    AND t.NAME = t1.NAME

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the concept of triggers to achieve this task:

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

You'll have to create an after Update/insert trigger on **kamp2** table and in that trigger you'll update **liga** table

Or else handle this by backend php script.

Comment: Why can't we use joins in update query? we can solve this with join and case statment

Comment: Yes, @Gordon Linoff has given the good solution using joins and case,,,

Comment: sorry, my bad edited the answer to avoid any wrong information.